# Is there a Caffeine feature that will purge a particular item from the cache after defined time and recreates it at the same time?

Tags: caching, java-8, guava, caffeine-cache

ExpireAfter will only purge the item but will not re-create the item. So what I need to do is, after a predefined interval, I need to purge a particular item from the cache and at the same time I need to recreate it.  It might recreate with same data if there is no change in the data. Assuming the data was changed, the recreating will give the latest object.

My idea was to retrieve latest item form the cache all the time. In contrast, the Refresh feature (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Refresh) will provide the stale item for the first request and does an asynchronous loading. So for the second request the cache will provide the latest object.

- Asynchronous removal listener that re-fetches the expired entry
  should work in my case. Can you please provide me some information on
  how to achieve this?
- I'm also curious to know how the scheduled task can do it?

**Assuming cache can address the following two cases:**

**Subsequent requests case:**

- I understand the refreshAfterWrite will provide the stale entry for
  the first time but for the second request, what happens if the cache
  hasn't yet completed loading the expired entry?
- Does cache blocks the second request, completes the re-fetch, and
  then provide the latest value to the second request?.
- The idea is to make the cache provides the latest data after the
  defined entry expiry time.

**In the case where the cache has to load values equal to its capacity at one shot:**

- Let say the cache size is 100 and the time to load all the 100 items
  is 2 minutes.
- Assuming the first request would load 100 items into the cache at the
  same time, after the defined expiry time, the cache should evict and
  re-fetch all the 100 elements.
- For the second request to access items from those 100 items, how can
  I make the cache smart enough so that it returns the entries that
  have been re-loaded and asynchronously re-loads the other entries?.
- The idea is not to block any request for an existing entry. Serve the
  request for an existing entry and do the re-load for the remaining
  expired entries.

Comment: (1) Would a scheduled task that iterates over the entries and reload them work? 
(2) Would an asynchronous removal listener that refetches the expired entry work?

Comment: Thank you @BenManes for quick reply. I have updated the main question as I have too much information for replying back to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Asynchronous removal listener that re-fetches the expired entry should work in my case. Can you please provide me some information on how to achieve this?

The removal listener requires a reference to the cache, but that is not available during construction. If it calls a private method instead then the uninitialized field isn't captured and it can be resolved at runtime.

```java
Cache<K, V> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .removalListener((K key, V value, RemovalCause cause) -> {
      if (cause == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
        reload(key);
      }
    }).build();

private void reload(K key) {
  cache.get(key, k -> /* load */);
}
```

> I'm also curious to know how the scheduled task can do it?

If you are reloading all entries then you might not even need a key-value cache. In that case the simplest approach would be to reload an immutable map.

```java
volatile ImmutableMap<K, V> data = load();

scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> data = load(), 
    /* initial */ 1, /* period */ 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

> I understand the refreshAfterWrite will provide the stale entry for the first time but for the second request, what happens if the cache hasn't yet completed loading the expired entry?

The subsequent requests obtain the stale entry until either (a) the refresh completes and updates the mappings or (b) the entry was removed and the caller must reload. The case of (b) can occur if the entry expired while the refresh was in progress, where returning the stale value is no longer an option.

> Does cache blocks the second request, completes the re-fetch, and then provide the latest value to the second request?.

No, the stale but valid value is returned. This is to let the refresh hide the latency of reloading a popular entry. For example an application configuration that is used by all requests would block when expired, causing periodic delays. The refresh would be triggered early, reload, and the callers would never observe it absent. This hides latencies, while also allowing idle entries to expire and fade away.

> In the case where the cache has to load values equal to its capacity at one shot... after the defined expiry time, the cache should evict and re-fetch all the 100 elements.

The unclear part of your description is if the cache reloads only the entries being accessed within the refresh period or if it reloads the entire contents. The former is what Caffeine offers, while the latter is better served with an explicit scheduling thread.